# Ativar função ao publicar post agendado wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Ola,
tenho um site em wordpress que faço agendamento de posts. O que eu quero é que após ele ser publicado, ative uma função que faça alguma coisa.

Eu vi que tem como colocar no functions.php mas não sei como chamo essa função após os posts agendados serem publicados.

Por exemplo tenho um post agendado para 12:00, outro para 13:00, outro para 14:00. Toda vez que for publicado um post agendado essa função é chamada.

Como faço isso?

OBS: Não quero utilizar plugins.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem algumas alternativas pra isso, que em geral envolvem interceptar a mudança de estado do post e rodar o seu codigo.

Você pode escolher quais dessas actions se encaixam melhor com o que pretende fazer:

```
// Se o código deve rodar apenas quando um post agendado é publicado
add_action(  'publish_future_post',  'publica_post' );
function publica_post( $post_id ) { // Seu código aqui
}

// Se o código deve rodar sempre que houver uma transição de status
// por exemplo, de rascunho para agendado, ou de rascunho para publicado
add_action(  'transition_post_status',  'publica_post', 10, 3 );
function publica_post( $novo_status, $antigo_status, $post ) { // Seu código aqui
}

// Se o código deve rodar sempre que um post for publicado
add_action(  'publish_post',  'publica_post', 10, 2 );
function publica_post( $post_id, $post ) { // Seu código aqui
}
```

[publish_future_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_future_post)

[transition_post_status](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/)

[{new_status}_{$post->post_type}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/)

Comment: Fantastico, eh isso mesmo!